# What is the use to the memories that you unlock?

Tags: from-dust

If you finish all levels, you have unlocked most memories. But what is the benefit of unlocking those memories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlocking memories is part of the games storyline and brings extra information into the game. It doesn't do that much and is more a reference to finding and completing every small part of the game like finding a hidden rune or getting full vegetation on a map. There are also achievements to my knowledge to unlock all the memories.

Also there is [a FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/997722-from-dust/faqs/62799) that probably goes into more of it.